# UICollectionViewCell doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How can I make the `UICollectionViewCell` appear? The `CollectionView` background does appear, but the cell doesn't, but I don't understand why not. Please check this code. [Full source code is here (github)](https://github.com/skymintmocha/testcode)

```
class itemsCollectionView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var myItemCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = CGFloat(5.0)
    layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal

    myItemCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 300, 100), collectionViewLayout: layout)
    myItemCollectionView.dataSource = self
    myItemCollectionView.delegate = self
    myItemCollectionView.registerClass(ItemCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CELLID)
    myItemCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    self.view.addSubview(myItemCollectionView)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate/datasource methods for collection view is not been called in "itemsCollectionView". I just changed the itemsCollectionView call in ItemGroupCell for time being and its working

Add a view controller  variable in **ItemGroupCell**

```
let itemVC : UIViewController = {

     let itemCollectionView = itemsCollectionView()
     return itemCollectionView
}()
```

Change the "*cellForItemAtIndexPath*" in **MainViewController** like this

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let groupCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifierID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemGroupCell

     //        if let groupName = groupMenu[indexPath.item].groupName    {
     //            groupCell.groupName.text = groupName
     //        }   

    // Configure the cell

    groupCell.Info = groupInfo[indexPath.item]

    groupCell.addSubview(groupCell.itemVC.view)
    groupCell.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-15-[v0]-15-|", views: groupCell.itemVC.view)

    return groupCell
}
```

Hope its working...

Comment: thank, you! . your comment is very good hint for me!
But i have another question...
your solution  is  ...below...
-----------------
let itemVC : UIViewController = {
        
        let itemCollectionView = itemsCollectionView()
        return itemCollectionView
    }()
--------
and addSubview(grouitemVC.view)

this(your) code  is appear the custome cell.

Comment: But..my ..code... is not appeared...customs cell...

let itemView: UIView = { let itemCollectionView = itemsCollectionView()
        let uico = itemCollectionView.view!
         return uico        
    }()
--------
and addSubView (iteView)

I do not know why the two results are different.
is not same??

Comment: What my understandings are adding a view controller to a subview  using "addsubview" is not a recommended way , because the  sub-controller won't call some delegate methods . Container view controllers are one good way to implement child view controllers

Answer (score 0):

Only Check two things :

1>> If you didn't applied `customCollectionViewCell` then Apply.

2>> Also Take care about reuseIdentifier of that Priority Cell.

Don't Use default. Still any query ask me here.

Comment: umm..i don't use default value... Did you see the github?

Comment: Yes, I see. It's all ok. But I suggest you to do minor fault in your program that can be handled by you. Try only one time by taking default cell then.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your collection view cell class as

```
  contentView.addSubview(imageview)
```

Or you can just add this line in your cell for item at index method

```
  yourCollectionViewCell.addSubview(yourCollectionViewCell.imageview)
```